Spring Cloud Kafka Binder setting auto-offset-reset with consumer group specified does not change default
I am trying to read from latest available offset (no offset commited for consumer group), so I specify in properties
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.process-in-0.group=test-group
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.process-in-0.auto-offset-reset=latest

But in logs ConsumerConfig values are set to earliest.
If I remove group setting, leaving only:

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.process-in-0.auto-offset-reset=latest

It starts reading only new messages for anonymous consumer. How to make this work also for consumer group?

Anonymous consumers (the ones without an explicit group.id), will always receive records from the latest only. The consumers with a group.id by default, receive records from the earliest. To change this to the latest, you need to set the start-offset property on the proper Kafka binding.
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.process-in-0.consumer.start-offset=latest.
Relevant sections from the reference docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/reference/4.1-SNAPSHOT/kafka/kafka-binder/config-options.html#kafka-consumer-properties
and
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/reference/4.1-SNAPSHOT/kafka/kafka-binder/reset-offsets.html

Thanks. The problem was that i tried this config with startOffset property as in documentation

both links give "404 Page not Found"
